# Netsuite suitescript 2.0

Tags: suitescript

i want to create a confirmation message in view mode using message.create module i tried in the follwing way as shown in code:
first i took a user event script in view mode and added a button in before load and on click of the button a client script is triggered to create the message
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget'],

function(ui) {

```
/**
 * Function definition to be triggered before record is loaded.
 *
 * @param {Object} scriptContext
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
 * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type
 * @param {Form} scriptContext.form - Current form
 * @Since 2015.2
 */
function beforeLoad(scriptContext) {
    if (scriptContext.type !== scriptContext.UserEventType.VIEW)
        { 
            log.debug("triggered");
             var Form=scriptContext.form;
             Form.addButton({
                    id : 'custpage_message',
                    label : 'message',
                    functionName:'message'
                });
             form.clientScriptFileId = 18249;
        }
}



return {
    beforeLoad: beforeLoad,

};
```

});
this is my client script:
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/ui/message'],

function(message) {

```
/**
 * Function to be executed after page is initialized.
 *
 * @param {Object} scriptContext
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
 * @param {string} scriptContext.mode - The mode in which the record is being accessed (create, copy, or edit)
 *
 * @since 2015.2
 */
function pageInit(scriptContext) {

}
function message()
{
     var myMsg = message.create({
            title: "My Title", 
            message: "My Message", 
            type: message.Type.CONFIRMATION
        });
}

return {
    pageInit: pageInit,
    message:message
};
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Thing Message function Conflicting. Just Rename the message function and try it.

Comment: if i keep alerts they are triggering but message is not getting displayed @Praveen Kumar

Comment: just rename the function name

Comment: don't use message as function name use other name

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myMsg = message.create({
                title: "My Title", 
                message: "My Message", 
                type: message.Type.CONFIRMATION
            });
         myMsg.show(); -- you missed that statement
```

-- In User event script

```
if (scriptContext.type !== scriptContext.UserEventType.VIEW)
        { 
            log.debug("triggered");
             var Form=scriptContext.form;
             Form.addButton({
                    id : 'custpage_message',
                    label : 'message',
                    functionName:'testmessage()'
                });
             Form.clientScriptFileId = 115069;
        }
```

as above code view mode but not created because u check the type not equal to view.

Comment: tried doing like this but still it is not working:
       alert('triggered');
      var myMsg = message.create({
             title: "My Title", 
             message: "My Message", 
             type: message.Type.CONFIRMATION
         });
      myMsg.show({ duration : 1500 });@Praveen Kumar

Comment: in view mode if (scriptContext.type === scriptContext.UserEventType.VIEW)

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * @NApiVersion 2.x
     * @NScriptType ClientScript
     * @NModuleScope SameAccount
     */
    define(['N/ui/message'],

    function(message) {

        function pageInit(scriptContext) {

        }
        function testmessage()
        {
            debugger;
             var myMsg = message.create({
                    title: "My Title", 
                    message: "My Message", 
                    type: message.Type.CONFIRMATION
                });
             myMsg.show();
        }

        return {
            pageInit: pageInit,
            testmessage:testmessage
        };
    });

/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define([],

function() {

    /**
     * Function definition to be triggered before record is loaded.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type
     * @param {Form} scriptContext.form - Current form
     * @Since 2015.2
     */
    function beforeLoad(scriptContext) {
        if (scriptContext.type == scriptContext.UserEventType.VIEW)
        { 
            log.debug("triggered");
             var Form=scriptContext.form;
             Form.addButton({
                    id : 'custpage_message',
                    label : 'message',
                    functionName:'testmessage'
                });
             Form.clientScriptFileId = 115069;
        }
    }

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad

    };


});
```